# Mysql count id query

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime-generation

I'm using mysql table like this one:

```
|  userid  |  regdate   | question  | answer  |
-----------------------------------------------
      1      2010-10-14   question 1  answer1
      2      2010-10-14   question 2  answer2    
      3      2010-10-15   question 3  answer3
      4      2010-10-16   question 4  answer4
```

I want to count registered users per day and the number of questions and answers sent per day. Can I do it with one mysql query and how?

The result should be something like:

```
|  regdate  |  new users  |  questions sent  | answers sent  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
 2010-10-14        2               2                 2
 2010-10-15        1               1                 1
 2010-10-16        1               1                 1
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
SELECT regadte, 
       COUNT(userid) as new_users, 
       COUNT(question) as questions_sent, 
       COUNT(answer) as answers_sent 
FROM table 
GROUP BY regdate;
```

I am not sure though because, do you mean "newly registered users" or "logged in users" ? Also, from your table, it looks like a user has to send an answer for each question, which I doubt is the case...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select regdate,count(userid) as new_users,count(question) as question_sent,count(answer) as answers_sent
from table_name group by regdate
```